# What is the difference between jsonify and tojson in Flask?

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I want to use some data from my Flask view in a JavaScript block in my template.  I tried using `jsonify` and `tojson`, but that gave an error.  What is the difference between the two?  How do I pass JSON to JavaScript in a template?

```
@app.route('/stocks')
def stocks():
    stocks = jsonify({"aapl":{"price":700, "volume":5000000}, "goog":{"price":655, "volume":9750000}})
    return render_template("stocks.html", stocks=stocks)
```

```html
<script>var zipcodes = {{ stocks|tojson }};</script>
```

```
TypeError: <Response 21 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to do. what templating engine do you use ?

Comment: Jinja I believe, I think that is what comes with Flask :)

Comment: and to solve your current problem you just need to pass the ``{"aapl":{"price":700, "volume":5000000}, "goog":{"price":655, "volume":9750000}}`` directly to jinja as stocks without using ``jsonify``

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`jsonify` returns a `Response` object to be returned from the Flask view as a JSON response to the client so in this case `stocks` is not a JSON object but a `Response` object.

If you want to use JSON but not directly return it to the client by using, you can use the `tojson` filter to convert an object to JSON in the template.

When you need to have JSON in your template, such as to use it in a JavaScript variable, you should use `tojson`.  When you need to return a JSON response to the client you should use `jsonify`.

Comment: Ok, so too make sure I understand. When loading the dictionary to the page from the template it does not have to be in Json. But to use that data in JS I use `tojson`. Now when doing an AJAX call for new information, that is when I would use `jsonify`.

Comment: you got it exactly ;)

Comment: such as to use it in a JavaScript variable, you should use tojson: I tried set the value with the filter and without the filter nothing changed in JavaScript, why and is tojson required?

Comment: Maybe it was a simpler case and the were no need to use `tojson`. I think it'd be wise to always use `tojson` in such cases.